# Export a page with web parts and import to another site

Tags: web-part, export, team-sites

I have a web page in the documents library configured in a certain way with all the web parts set up.  I created this on a test team site.

How can I export this page to a production team site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exporting and importing as html will not work in SharePoint as it refers lots of controls and files internally

> Thee best suggested option would be to open the page in designer and copy the content to target page** but make sure all the those web
>   parts are already in the web part gallery and fully functional.

---

To check all webparts are in the gallery, initially u should enable the features related to them in ur production site.

Comment: Euh no, I'm not agree. If you have a customized page, e.g. with a custom page layout, custom masterpage etc, you will lost all your references. So this option is on my opinion, not a best option

Comment: i do agree about master pages, custom page layouts or any other UI and no UI references. the question over here doesn't indicate any custom page layouts so i refereed it to regular team site pages with some set of web parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell to export your page and to import it on the production team site.

```
Export-SPWeb -identity "http://url" -ItemUrl "/default.aspx"  -Path "c:\default.aspx"     
Import-SPWeb -identity "http://url" -Path "C:\default.aspx"
```

Don't forget to have same structure on both side. E.g. if you've got custom page layout, first install page layouts on production team site.

Regards,